# POV-Ray clay texture

Tags: textures, povray, clay

Does anyone know how to simulate a clay texture in POV-Ray? Would also love something that could create an object that has the roughness of clay. Is there some sort of mathematical function that can produce a clay smooth random bump?

Answer (score 1):

If you literally mean "texture" as povray defines it, I'm not much help. But if you want an object whose surface looks like smooth bumps, try investigating the blob object, or perhaps the noise3d function.

http://www.povray.org/documentation/view/3.6.1/71/

Comment: If you want a pictorial example, look at my avatar: it's a povray blob. If you want the code for a very simple example (a crude hand), look at the bottom of the link. If you want a more complicated example, elaborate what you want to see.

Comment: Was hoping more for a clay texture example